# reverse(char *s, int dim); Recursive reverse a string in place without using strlen

Tags: c, recursion

Is it possible to reverse a string in place without using strlen, using recursion and with this definition?

```
void reverse(char *s, int dim);
```

The only thing I could do was:

```
void reverse(char *s, int dim)
{
    int a = dim;
    int b = strlen(s) - 1 - dim;

    if ((a - b) <= 0)
        return;

    swap(s[a], s[b]);

    reverse(s, dim - 1);
}
```

But I would like to do that **without using strlen** and without defining a similar function. Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot reverse a range whose length you don't know. (You can perhaps discover the length by ways other than, but equivalent to, `strlen`, but you'd only do a worse job of it that `strlen` would.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao.  Come va?

As for me I would declare the function the following way

```
char * reverse( char *s, size_t n );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * reverse( char *s, size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        char c = s[0];
        s[0] = s[n-1];
        s[n-1] = c;
        reverse( s + 1, n - 2 );
    }

    return s;
}    


int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Hello misiMe";

    puts( s );
    puts( reverse( s , sizeof( s ) - 1 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello misiMe
eMisim olleH
```

Comment: Io bene, tu? Sorry, couldn't resist.